# There are two different times so isn't it necessary to use past perfect instead of past simple with 'use'

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense, past-vs-past-perfect

> Capital expenditure of their company in the year 2001 was clearly below the spending in the year 2000 when they **used** about half the investments for the concept conversion.

There are two years 2000 and 2001 and 2000 was before 2001 that is why l think

Comment: The perfect tenses are used to establish a relationship between two events, e.g. *"They **had used** something before they did something else"*.  There is no such relationship in this sentence.  The *use* was a one-time thing.   If this is still confusing, please add more detail to your question to help explain why you think the past perfect makes more sense.

Comment: Andrew there are two years 2000 and 2001 and 2000 was before  2001 that is why l think

Answer (score 2):

The past perfect is rarely required: in most uses it is a choice that the speaker or writer may make to establish not just the temporal relationship between two events or circumstances, but also where the temporal focus is to be set.

Here, the times are indicated by the years, so it is absolutely not necessary to use the past perfect.

If the writer had used it, this would be saying something more than "event A happened before event B": they would also be saying "and I am setting my temporal focus at event B". This might be important if they then went on and talked about what happened as a consequence of event B: if they didn't use the past perfect, it might be unclear if they were talking about what followed event B or what followed event A. (It might still be clear which they meant for other reasons).

But if they have no need to establish a temporal focus, then there is no need to use the past perfect.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) you made it clear